# change fade to elastic ... effect

Tags: jquery, effect

Making a testimonial slider, and wondered how I would change effect from fade to something like elastic , in out bounce etc.

I have made a fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/Gx2TR/

our js is:

```
 var slider = function() {
    $('#testimonials .slide').filter(':visible').fadeOut(1000,function(){
        if($(this).next('li.slide').size()){
            $(this).next().fadeIn(2000);
        }
        else{
            $('#testimonials .slide').eq(0).fadeIn(1000);
        }
    });
};
var interval = setInterval(slider, 6000);
$('#testimonials .slide').hover(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
}, function() {
    interval = setInterval(slider, 6000);
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/animate/  see  examples, i thing they're just what you need.

Comment: I prefer the [easing plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) to jQuery's built-in effects. It has bounce, elastic, and many more.